# How to use interface default implementation in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oop, entity-framework-core, abstract-class

I have classes which are inherits from base class.

```
public class Car : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        // update method goes here
    }
}


public abstract class BaseEntity
{
    public Guid Id { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
}
```

I want to have an interface or something else where I can audit this entity changes. I made an interface and added default implementation like below :

```
public interface IAuditable
{
    // userNameProvider goes here
    DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
    Guid CreatedBy { get; set; }

    void Audit()
    {
        CreatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
        // CreatedBy =  userNameProvider.GetUserId();
    }
}
```

But the issue is that I need to cast my Car into this interface in order to call Audit method. As it's not forced to implement in the Car class, I guess I can just forget it or something else. I want a solution which could be reusable for all entities deriving from this interface just by calling one method and not to be afraid to forget Audit method. I'd highly appreciate your suggestions. Thanks

Example code what is working right now but need to simplify :

```
var car = new Car("bmw");

Console.WriteLine(car.CreatedTime);

public class Car : BaseEntity, IAuditable
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }

    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        (this as IAuditable).Audit();
        // update method goes here
    }
}
```

I mentioned above what I did and my expectation, please take a look :)

Comment: What is wrong with `public class Car : BaseEntity, IAuditable`?

Comment: that's not wrong but how I am supposed to force our team members to use Audit method when they just implement this new interface? My goal is to reduce code duplications and have a centralized method or interface for audit logic. That would be same for all entities

Comment: "_But the issue is that I need to cast my Car into this interface_" Is that neccessary? Does the code that audits not depend on `IAuditable` rather than a particular implementation?

Comment: So the question is "How to invoke a method on any change of any property"?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay without casting I can't call `Audit` method

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy not exactly. I want to control where I'll call `Audit` method. I have some custom logic for defining when I need to update these DateTime properties so that's why I wanted to have an interface with default implementation which is gonna force me to not forget about `Audit` method and I thought using interface will reduce code duplication

Comment: An explicit cast isn't necessary if the code depends on `IAuditable`. You can use a `Car` instance in place of `IAuditable` as it implements that interface.

Comment: Why not to move `Audit()` into `BaseEntity`?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay I updated my question and added code snippet to describe current implementation. Please take a look

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I can't move this functionality to `BaseEntity` due to some restrictions. I need a workaround

Comment: Make your own `MyBaseEntity : BaseEntity` then

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy I don't wanna go by this way. I need exactly not to use abstract class

Comment: But you are free to call any method from any additional class?

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy not exactly. There should be two separate interfaces for `Create` and `Update` operations. That's the main reason why I can't use abstract class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use default interface methods directly if you don't implement them in the concrete class. However, you can add an extension method to make calling the default interface method easier:

```cs
public static class AuditableExtensions
{
    public static void Audit(this IAuditable auditable)
    {
        auditable.Audit();
    }
}

// usage:

Car car = new Car();
car.Audit();

// or

public class Car : BaseEntity, IAuditable
{
    public Car()
    {
        this.Audit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can override your DbContext `SaveChangesAsync` method

```cs
public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(bool acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    foreach (var e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                                   .Where(i => i.State == EntityState.Added
                                            || i.State == EntityState.Modified)
                                   .Select(i => i.Entity)
                                   .OfType<IAuditable>())
    {
        e.Audit();
    }

    return base.SaveChangesAsync(acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, cancellationToken);
}
```

This will ensure that all `IAuditable` entities modified through your DB Context will have their `Audit` method called.

Comment: I got your point, but I don't need it to be done in DbContext or somewhere else. I want to control this `Audit` logic in each entity cause I have some custom logic

Comment: But each entity will have own audit logic, you will just have a single point where you call that logic.

Comment: I want to call `Audit` method let's say after doing some entity specific logic, cause I have relations with other entities and in some cases I need to update my entity based on related entity and vice versa. That's the reason I can't use single point to call all `Audit` methods

Answer (score 0):

You can use an external processing class like this:

```
public class Car : BaseEntity, IAuditable
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public Car(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Auditor.Audit(this);
    }
}

public static class Auditor
{
    public static void Audit(IAuditable entity)
    {
        entity.Audit();
    }
}
```